# jQuery or Javascript Click function change or add id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the text "mars-on-newyork" from this links, this is how the links looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li> 
<a href="google.com/finder.php?offer=mars-on-newyork"> 
<img class="the-button-red"/> 
</a> 
  </li>
  <li> 
<a href="google.com/finder.php?offer=mars-on-newyork"> 
<img class="the-button-green"/> 
</a> 
  </li>
 <li> 
<a href="google.com/finder.php?offer=mars-on-newyork"> 
<img class="the-button-blue"/> 
</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

This code changes my images only:

```
function changeIt(objName) {
 var obj = document.getElementById(objName);
 var objId = new Array();
 objId[0] = "newyork";
 objId[1] = "paris";
 objId[2] = "tokyo";
 var i;
 var tempObj;
for (i = 0; i < objId.length; i++) {
    if (objName == objId[i]) {
        obj.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        tempObj = document.getElementById(objId[i]);
        tempObj.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  return;
}
```

and here is the rest of the html from which the java script changes only the pictures:

```
<div id="newyork">
 <a href="#"> 
   <img src="newyork.jpg"/> 
</a>
</div> 

<div id="paris" style="display:none">
<img src="paris.jpg" border="0" alt="one"/>
</div> 
<div id="tokyo" style="display:none">
<img src="tokyo.jpg" border="0" alt="two" />
</div> 

<div style="display:none;">
<a id="one" href="#" onclick="changeIt('newyork');"><img src="newyork.jpg" border="0"      alt="one"/></a> 
</div> 

<div>
<a id="one" href="#" onclick="changeIt('paris');"><img src="paris.jpg" border="0" alt="one"/></a> 
</div> 

<div>
<a id="two" href="#" onclick="changeIt('tokyo');"><img src="tokyo.jpg" border="0" alt="two"/></a> 
</div>
```

If i click on
     `<a id="one" href="#" onclick="changeIt('paris');"><img src="paris.jpg" border="0"        alt="one"/></a>`

i want the text from the links on the ul to change from this:

href="google.com/finder.php?offer=mars-on-newyork

to this:

href="google.com/finder.php?offer=mars-on-paris

and if i click on
  `<a id="one" href="#" onclick="changeIt('tokyo');"><img src="paris.jpg" border="0"        alt="one"/></a>`

it changes it to 
href="google.com/finder.php?offer=mars-on-tokyo

i want the java script to work like it does, how it changes the images but i also want to take advantage of the click to change the text.

thanks!

---

I see how it is now, i guess my post wasn't good enough to have piqued you're interest's, i guess i would have to pay a freelancer to help me, thanks anyways guys for your time and help!

Comment: _Javascript is not Java_

Comment: _"lets say if i click on
`<div id="paris" style="display:none">`"_ - How can you click on something that isn't displayed?

Comment: Sorry about that, somehow i knew  that there was something wrong, thanks Slaks.

Comment: Wow, what a mess. Can you just post the relevant code to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer to "*Is it possible to add or change and id from a link?*":

```
$('#link').attr('id', 'yourNewId'); // Change id
```

Quick solution to "*What I also want is not to just change the images but also the id or link*"

```
$('#link').attr('href', 'yourNewUrl'); // Change link
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it a little hard to understand what you're trying to do, but...

> what i also want is not to just change the images but also the id or link from the ul list e.g

OK, to change the link, i.e., the `href` property of all anchor elements in your ul list, assuming the URL has a fixed format and we can just replace whatever comes after the last "-":

```
// assume objName = "paris" or whatever

$("ul a").attr("href", function(i, oldVal) {
   return oldVal.substr(0, oldVal.lastIndexOf("-") + 1) + objName;
});
```

If you pass the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) a callback function it will call that function for each element and pass the function the current value - you then return the new value.

The elements in question don't seem to have an `id` at the moment, so I'm not sure what you mean by wanting to change it.